# Cannot store cookie data on IIS 7.5

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies, iis-7.5

This is my problem;
I currently work on a CodeIgniter application and the client wants us to deploy it on an IIS server.

My Dev machine is a Windows 7 box running IIS 7.5 and my application works just fine. The problem starts when I deploy it to the remote machine, a Windows 2008 server. There, I cannot use sessions no matter what.

My guess is that this is a server issue, because if I try to add the following line to my Sessions.php file

```
function _set_cookie($cookie_data = NULL)
{
    if (is_null($cookie_data))
    {
        $cookie_data = $this->userdata;
    }

    // Serialize the userdata for the cookie
    $cookie_data = $this->_serialize($cookie_data);

    if ($this->sess_encrypt_cookie == TRUE)
    {
        $cookie_data = $this->CI->encrypt->encode($cookie_data);
    }
    else
    {
        // if encryption is not used, we provide an md5 hash to prevent userside tampering
        $cookie_data = $cookie_data.md5($cookie_data.$this->encryption_key);
    }

    $expire = ($this->sess_expire_on_close === TRUE) ? 0 : $this->sess_expiration + time();

    // Set the cookie
    setcookie(
                $this->sess_cookie_name,
                $cookie_data,
                $expire,
                $this->cookie_path,
                $this->cookie_domain,
                $this->cookie_secure
            );

//This is the added line
var_dump($_COOKIE);die;
}
```

All I get as output is

```
Array()
```

Which means that the native setcookie function doesn't do anything... 
Thank you for your time!

**[EDIT]**

Looks like the session works if I set the cookie_secure flag to false... It definitely works now but I can't seem to figure out why... I'll leave the topic as unresolved for a few days just in case someone can explain why this happens :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation for the cookie_secure flag equalling true requires the user agent (browser) to use https for any cookies to be set. Were you using https in your testing?

Comment: Well, it seems like I had this setting set to FALSE in my dev machine and TRUE to the remote... I didn't even notice the config.php files were different :/ Well, that was it!